# Obtener valor de un atributo de un objeto y ponerlo en una variable en jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jstl

Necesito obtener el valor de un atributo de un objeto(usuario.estado) y ponerlo dentro de una variable(estado) de JSP para luego hacer sentencias if dependiendo de esa variable. 
Aquí el código.

```
<tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><c:out value="${usuario.id}"/></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${usuario.apellidos}"/></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${usuario.nombre}"/></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${usuario.usuario}"/></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${usuario.clave}"/></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${usuario.permisos}"/></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${usuario.estado}"/></td>
                    <% String estado=(AQUI ES DONDE NECESITO OBTENER EL VALOR DE usuario.estado);%>
                    <td><form action=""><button type="button" class="btn 
btn-block btn-info btn-xs" name="${usuario.usuario }" value="${usuario.usuario }">Editar</button></form></td>
                    <td><form action="DeshabilitaServlet" method="post">
```

Desactivado
                        Eliminar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya encontré una solucion y es usando el propio JSTL

```
<tbody><tr>
              <c:forEach var="usuario" items="${listarUsuario}">

                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <!-- <td><c:out value="${usuario.id}"/></td> -->
                    <td><c:out value="${usuario.apellido_p}"/></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${usuario.apellido_m}"/></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${usuario.nombre}"/></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${usuario.usuario}"/></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${usuario.clave}"/></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${usuario.permisos}"/></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${usuario.estado}"/></td>
                    <td><form action="editaServlet"><button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-info btn-xs" name="ediusario" value="${usuario.usuario }">Editar</button></form></td>
                    <c:choose>
                        <c:when test="${usuario.estado=='1'}">
                                <td><form action="DeshabilitaServlet" method="post"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-success btn-xs" name="usu" value="${usuario.usuario }">Activado</button></form></td>  
                        </c:when>
                        <c:when test="${usuario.estado=='0'}">
                                <td><form action="DeshabilitaServlet" method="post"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-warning btn-xs"  name="usu" value="${usuario.usuario }">Desactivado</button></form></td>  
                        </c:when>     
                    </c:choose>

                    <td><form action="EliminarServlet" method="post"> <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-danger btn-xs" name="elimusuario" value="${usuario.usuario }">Eliminar</button></form></td>




                    <!-- <td><a href="<s:url action="edit"><s:param name="user.id"><c:out value="${user.id}"/></s:param></s:url>" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">Editar</a></td>
                    <td><a href="delete.action?user.id=<c:out value="${user.id}"/>"><button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">Delete</button></a></td>  -->

                </tr>
                </tbody>
                </c:forEach>
          </tbody>
```

Con el  y los  aparte de poder usarlos como un if , estos pueden usar las variables que el servlet manda, en este caso capturar usuario.estado y dependiendo de si es 1 o 0 ejecutar una accion